# Django JsonResponse sends duplicate pieces of object sometimes and not others

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

This is a super weird bug I'm running into.  I have a python script that generates a JSON object which I want to respond with using `JsonReponse`.  This response successfully comes back, but sometimes it contains multiple parts of the object, sometimes it contains one, and it just goes up and down and all over the place in terms of the number of copies it sends back.  No idea how this is even possible.

This is a web crawler sending back JSON for nodes and edges of a graph, and duplicate nodes/edges are coming back seemingly at random.  The script that does the web crawling and generates the JSON works correctly every time though, it's only when it's used in the context of making a request to Django that the problem occurs.

My views.py has a function like this that handles a web crawler script.

```
def webcrawler(request):
    source = request.GET.get('source')
    method = request.GET.get('method')
    nodes = request.GET.get('nodes')
    depth = request.GET.get('depth')
    keyword = request.GET.get('keyword')
    webcrawler = WebCrawler(source, method, nodes, depth, keyword)
    data = webcrawler.jsonSerialize()
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

My `jsonSerialize()` function looks like this:

```
def jsonSerialize(self):
    for n in self.graph.nodes:
        n.sourceNodes = []
    self.graph.edges = list(self.graph.edges)
    return json.dumps(self.graph, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

Why would I be getting random numbers of copies back from this response?  I'm making a new request every time and create a new object every time, but it seems like the number of objects sent back just grows and sometimes goes up an down.  If I open a new tab and make a new request, the same thing happens.  What could possibly be the cause of this?

For example, if I keep making the same request `webcrawler?source=http://www.google.com&method=BFS&nodes=5&depth=0&keyword=google`

Sometimes it looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google",
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google Images",
      "index": 4
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "YouTube",
      "index": 3
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google News",
      "index": 2
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google Maps",
      "index": 1
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 3
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 2
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

And sometimes it looks like this...with duplicate nodes and edges.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Gmail",
      "index": 1
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "https://www.google.com/intl/en/options/",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "\n      Our Products | Google\n    ",
      "index": 7
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google Images",
      "index": 6
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Meet Google Drive \u2013 One place for all your files",
      "index": 2
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google News",
      "index": 8
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google Maps",
      "index": 3
    },
    {
      "keyword": true,
      "url": "https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google Play",
      "index": 9
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.com/",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Sign in - Google Accounts",
      "index": 4
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "Google",
      "index": 0
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": " Google - Search Customization ",
      "index": 5
    },
    {
      "keyword": false,
      "url": "http://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1",
      "sourceNodes": [],
      "title": "YouTube",
      "index": 3
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 7
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 6
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 5
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 4
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 9
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 3
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 8
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

If I run the python script locally with the same arguments multiple times I do not see this adverse behavior however.  This makes me think it has something to do with the request/Django/JsonResponse, because the script appears to be running correctly.

Here's the code for my web crawler:

```
import urllib
# from urllib.request import urlopen
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import collections
from Graph import Graph
from Node import Node
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime
from timeout import timeout
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process
import json
import re
import pdb

class WebCrawler:
    def __init__(self, originUrl, method, totalNodes, depthLimit=None, keyword=None):
        self.originUrl = originUrl
        self.method = method
        self.totalNodes = int(totalNodes)
        self.nodeCount = 0
        self.depthLimit = int(depthLimit)
        self.currentDepth = 0
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.keywordUrls = []
        self.nodeUrlMap = {}
        self.nodesToVisit = []
        self.visitedUrls = set()
        self.graph = Graph()
        self.nodeIndex = 0
        self.storeCookie()
        originTitle = self.getTitle(originUrl)
        startNode = Node(originUrl, None, originTitle)
        self.crawl(startNode)

    def crawl(self, node):
        print("crawl(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        visited = node.url in self.visitedUrls
        if not visited:
            self.graph.addNode(node, self.nodeIndex)
            self.nodeIndex += 1
            self.nodeCount += 1
            self.visitedUrls.add(node.url)
        if node.sourceNodes: # If this is not the starting node
            sourceNode = node.sourceNodes.pop()
            if sourceNode.index is not None and node.index is not None:
                self.graph.addEdge(sourceNode.index, node.index) # Add an edge between sourceNode and node
        if not visited:
            soup = self.generateSoup(node.url)
            hasKeyword = self.checkForKeyword(soup, node.url)
            if hasKeyword:
                node.keyword = True
            links = self.findLinks(soup)
            links = self.validLinks(links)
            links = {l for l in links} # Remove duplicate links
            if links:
                if self.method == "BFS":
                    self.bfs(node, links)
                else: # DFS
                    self.currentDepth += 1
                    if self.currentDepth >= self.depthLimit: # If depth limit reached, getNextNode (up a level)
                        self.currentDepth = 0 # Reset currentDepth
                        self.getNextNode()
                    else: # Otherwise, keep going deeper
                        self.dfs(node, links)
            else: # No links present
                self.getNextNode()
        else: # Avoid infinite loop
            self.getNextNode()

    def validLinks(self, links):
        print("validLinks(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        validLinks = []
        for link in links:
            # Only add links while there is still room
            if self.nodeCount + len(validLinks) <= self.totalNodes:
                if self.isValidUrl(link):
                    validLinks.append(link)
        return validLinks

    def isValidUrl(self, url):
        print("isValidUrl(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        extensionBlacklist = ["zip", "dmg", "msi", "tar", "exe", "sisx"]
        for x in extensionBlacklist:
            if x in url:
                return False
        if "http" not in url: return False
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        if not bool(parsed_url.scheme): return False
        try:
            self.testRequest(url)
        except:
            return False
        return True

    @timeout(1)
    def testRequest(self, url):
        requests.head(url)

    def getNextNode(self):
        print("getNextNode(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        if len(self.nodesToVisit) is not 0 and not self.nodeLimitReached():
            # We use the same data structure to store urlsToVisit for BFS and DFS,
            # and pop elements off the same way.  How the elements are added is
            # what's important.
            nextNode = self.nodesToVisit.pop()
            self.crawl(nextNode)
        else: # Crawl is over
            return

    def printGraph(self):
        for node in self.graph.nodes:
            print("\nNode:")
            if node.title:
                print("Index: " + str(node.index))
                print("Title: " + node.title)
                print("URL: " + node.url)
                print("Keyword: " + str(node.keyword))
        if self.graph.edges:
            print("\nEdges:")
            edgeCount = 0
            for e in self.graph.edges:
                print("Source: " + str(e.source) + " Target: " + str(e.target))
        if self.keywordUrls:
            print("\nKeyword URLs:")
            for k in self.keywordUrls:
                print("URL: " + k)
        print("\nJSON:")
        print(self.jsonSerialize())

    def jsonSerialize(self):
        for n in self.graph.nodes:
            n.sourceNodes = []
        self.graph.edges = list(self.graph.edges)
        self.graph.nodes = list(self.graph.nodes)
        return json.dumps(self.graph, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

    def storeCookie(self):
        # Store graph as cookie (do this one)
        pass

    def nodeLimitReached(self):
        return self.nodeCount >= self.totalNodes

    # Convert URL into soup
    def generateSoup(self, url):
        print("generateSoup(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        return soup

    # Parse soup to find links
    def findLinks(self, soup):
        print("findLinks(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        links = soup.findAll('a')
        hrefs = []
        for link in links:
            href = link.get('href', '')
            hrefs.append(href)
        return hrefs

    def getTitle(self, url):
        print("getTitle(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        soup = self.generateSoup(url)
        title = soup.title  # same as soup.find("title")
        if title is not None:
            return title.get_text()

    def bfs(self, currentNode, links):
        print("bfs(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        for link in links:
            # If url is not already visited, and nodesToVisit+nodeCount hasn't exceeded totalNodes
            if link not in self.visitedUrls and self.nodeCount + len(self.nodesToVisit) <= self.totalNodes:
                title = self.getTitle(link)
                newNode = Node(link, [currentNode], title)
                newNode.sourceNodes.insert(0, currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.insert(0, newNode)
                self.nodeUrlMap[link] = newNode
            elif link in self.nodeUrlMap: # Repeat URL, get existing node
                existingNode = self.nodeUrlMap[link]
                existingNode.sourceNodes.insert(0, currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.insert(0, existingNode)
        self.getNextNode()

    def dfs(self, currentNode, links):
        print("dfs(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        for link in links:
            if link not in self.visitedUrls:
                title = self.getTitle(link)
                newNode = Node(link, [currentNode], title)
                newNode.sourceNodes.append(currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.append(newNode)
            elif link in self.nodeUrlMap: # Repeat URL, get existing node
                existingNode = self.nodeUrlMap[link]
                existingNode.sourceNodes.append(currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.append(existingNode)
        self.getNextNode()

    def checkForKeyword(self, soup, url):
        if self.keyword != "":
            # If keyword found in soup, append url to keywordUrls
            if soup.body and soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('.*{0}.*'.format(self.keyword)), recursive=True):
                self.keywordUrls.append(url)
                return True
```

Comment: Can you paste an example json? In which way is it copied?

Comment: @Udi I added some example JSON.  What do you mean by 'which way is it copied?'

Comment: I don't see any duplicates - it's just different results.

Comment: @Udi Sorry, I didn't articulate the problem well.  It's not duplicate data per say, but old data from a previous request that is somehow getting persisted.  If you play with that URL and make a few different requests you'll see what I mean.  It's kind of hard to explain what's going on since the behavior seems to be so arbitrary.

Comment: Although this is OK, can you please change the name of the local variable `webcrawler` - so it won't be the same as the name of the view?

Comment: I think this is just different results - google might return different pages in different requests (for example when accessing from a different country/IP)

Comment: And: you are double-serializing your data: `JsonResponse(data)` is calling `json.dumps(data)` as well

Comment: @Udi It's not just that the results change, I wouldn't have a problem with that because links can be found in a different order, but the number of nodes and edges being returned changes.  Also, if I crawl google.com, and then crawl another URL, I will get results from both URL's.  The data is clearly being persisted somewhere somehow.

Comment: Can you paste some "bad" json instead of the example above (which is fine)?

Comment: @Udi The above IS bad JSON.  The request was made for 5 nodes, and it returned 5 on the first attempt.  On the second attempt, it returns 11 nodes.  The problem is that subsequent requests will contain data from previous requests.  If you want multiple different examples, it should be very easy to reproduce with the link I have provided.

Comment: I am quite sure this is a bug in the crawler. There is a state that is left from one crawl to another - probably in the graph.  Try adding `assert len(webcrawler.graph.nodes) <= nodes` to your code.

Comment: Are you using gunciorn with `--threads`? What is your gunicorn command line?

Comment: @Udi I added my web crawler code, but I'm still not sure why the issue would be coming from there if the script runs fine by itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `WebCrawler` is incorrectly initializing its `graph` property.  Instead of:

```
class WebCrawler:
    graph = Something()  # graph is a static class variable!!
```

Try:

```
class WebCrawler:
    def __init__(self, ...)
        self.graph = Something()  # graph is an instance variable
```

(If not - check `graph.edges`/`graph.nodes`'s initialization).

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  All my classes are properly using `__init__` methods and instance variables.  The script also runs fine by itself, the issue only appears when it is used in the context of this request using Django which makes me think the problem is coming from there.